# Execution time of different operators

Tags: c, optimization, cpu, timing, cpu-architecture

I was reading Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming and I noticed that he indicates that the DIV command takes 6 times longer than the ADD command in his MIX assembly language.

To test the relevancy to modern architecture, I wrote the following code snippet:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    clock_t start;
    unsigned int ia=0,ib=0,ic=0;
    int i;
    float fa=0.0,fb=0.0,fc=0.0;
    int sample_size=100000;

    if (argc > 1)
        sample_size = atoi(argv[1]);

#define TEST(OP) \
    start = clock();\
    for (i = 0; i < sample_size; ++i)\
        ic += (ia++) OP ((ib--)+1);\
    printf("%d,", (int)(clock() - start))
    TEST(+);
    TEST(*);
    TEST(/);
    TEST(%);
    TEST(>>);
    TEST(<<);
    TEST(&);
    TEST(|);
    TEST(^);
#undef TEST

//TEST must be redefined for floating point types
#define TEST(OP) \
    start = clock();\
    for (i = 0; i < sample_size; ++i)\
        fc += (fa+=0.5) OP ((fb-=0.5)+1);\
    printf("%d,", (int)(clock() - start))
    TEST(+);
    TEST(*);
    TEST(/);
#undef TEST

    printf("\n");
    return ic+fc;//to prevent optimization!
}
```

I then generated 4000 test samples (each containing a sample size of 100000 operations of each type) using this command line:

```
for i in {1..4000}; do ./test >> output.csv; done
```

Finally, I opened the results with Excel and graphed the averages. What I found was rather surprising. Here is the graph of the results:
[image: graph of results]

The actual averages were (from left-to-right): 463.36475,437.38475,806.59725,821.70975,419.56525,417.85725,426.35975,425.9445,423.792,549.91975,544.11825,543.11425

Overall this is what I expected (division and modulo are slow, as are floating point results).

My question is: why do both integer and floating-point multiplication execute faster than their addition counterparts? It is a small factor, but it is consistent across numerous tests. In TAOCP Knuth lists ADD as taking 2 units of time while MUL takes 10. Did something change in CPU architecture since then?

Comment: Division here is relatively fast because you are dividing n/(n+1). I replaced it with `(ia++) OP (17)` (just random odd number 17), and division gets a lot slower, by a factor of about 10 to 2. Can you mix up the test a little?

Comment: Originally I had it operating on rand() and rand(), but I found that it was both too slow and too noisy. I was able to cut down on variance significantly by swapping rand() with what I have. I'll run it again with half-rand()ing and

Comment: Results are similar, though my issue with ADD/MUL went away. I think you misunderstood my code. It is not `(ia++) OP (ia--)` but rather `(ia++) OP (ib--)` with both sides moving in opposite directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to test the execution time, look at the instructions produced in the assembly listing and look at the documentation for the processor for those instructions and note if the FPU is performing the operation or if it is directly performed in the code.

Then, add up the execution time for each instruction.

However, if the cpu is pipelined or multi threaded, the operation could take MUCH less time than calculated.

Comment: Pipelining on the FPU held the key. Each iteration I called the adding functionality to add 1 to the second value. Thus adding occasionally had a small delay. When I moved the +1 out (by making the second value a predetermined rand() value) I got much more consistent results.

Answer (score 4):

Different instructions take different amounts of time on the same CPU; and the same instructions can take different amounts of time on different CPUs. For example, for Intel's original Pentium 4 shifting was relatively expensive and addition was quite fast, so adding a register to itself was faster than shifting a register left by 1; and for Intel's recent CPUs shifting and addition are roughly the same speed (shifting is faster than it was on the original Pentium 4 and addition slower, in terms of "cycles").

To complicate things more, different CPUs may be able to do more or less at the same time, and have other differences that effect performance.

**In theory (and not necessarily in practice):**

Shifting and boolean operations (AND, OR, XOR) should be fastest (each bit can be done in parallel). Addition and subtraction should be next (relatively simple, but all bits of the result can't be done in parallel because of the carry from one pair of bits to the next).

Multiplication should be much slower as it involves many additions, but some of those additions can be done in parallel. For a simple example (using decimal digits not binary) something like 12 * 34 (with multiple digits) can be broken down into "single digit" form and becomes 2*4 + 2*3 * 10 + 1*4 * 10 + 1*3 * 100; where all "single digit" multiplications can be done in parallel, then 2 additions can be done in parallel, then the last addition can be done.

Division is mostly "compare and subtract if larger, repeated". It's the slowest because it can't be done in parallel (the results of the subtraction are needed for the next comparison). Modulo is the remainder of a division and essentially identical to division (and for most CPUs it's actually the same instruction - e.g. a `DIV` instruction gives you a quotient and a remainder).

For floating point; each number has 2 parts (significand and exponent), so things get a little more complicated. Floating point shifting is actually adding to or subtracting from the exponent (and should cost roughly the same as integer addition/subtraction). For floating point addition, subtraction and boolean operations you need to equalise the exponents, and after that you do the operation on the significands alone (and the "equalising" and "doing the operation" can't be done in parallel). Multiplication is multiplying the significands and adding the exponents (and adjusting the bias), where both parts can be done in parallel so the total cost is whichever is slowest (multiplying the significands); so it's as fast as integer multiplication. Division is dividing the significands and subtracting the exponents (and adjusting the bias), where both parts can be done in parallel and total cost is whichever is slowest (dividing the significands); so it's as fast as integer division.

*Note: I've simplified in various places to make it much easier to understand.*

Comment: That makes sense. I ran my own test, everything is about the same speed, except division for both integer and float is about 5 times slower.

Comment: Although logic ops could in theory be faster than add and sub, remember that CPUs compute in time units of whole clock cycles.  One common design optimization goal is to have add and sub complete in one cycle.  So although the circuit delay for AND would be faster, the result can't be *used* until the next whole clock cycle.  Having a two-cycle latency integer ALU has been shown to be a bad decision (the PowerPC 970 did, and it was a performance bottleneck).

Comment: Also, you CAN pipeline division.  It's just not worth the massive amount of circuit area, because divides aren't done that often.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that division and modulo (a division operation) is slower than addition. The reason behind this is the design of ALU (Arithmetic Logical Unit). The ALU is combination of parallel adders and logic-circuits. Division is performed by repeated subtraction, therefore needs more level of subtract logic making division slower than addition. The propagation delays of gates involved in division adds cherry on cake.